# Thunderbird: How to transfer CalDAV/CardDAV Connections from one Machine to another?

Tags: configuration, thunderbird, file-transfer

On my main machine I am running `Thunderbird` with `Lightning` and have several `CalDAV` calendars connected. Furthermore there is also a `CardDAV` address book hooked up.

**How can I transfer those CalDAV and CardDAV connections to a further machine?**

To get the mentioned connections available on a second machine I have the following options:

1. Create all connections completely from scratch  (-> annoying)
2. Copy the whole directory `~/.thunderbird` to the new machine (-> impractical, because mail profiles would be copied as well)
3. Copy only necessary files for calendars and the address book to the new machine (-> desired)

---

I want to avoid setting it up by hand. So: Which files do I have to copy from `~/.thunderbird`?

My guess is something like:

- File `storage.db`
- File `prefs.js` (only the lines with "calendar")
- Directory `calendar-data`

But where is the connection for `CardDAV` stored?

Comment: hello, a bit late to the party, but... :)    did you manage to reach your goal? I would say you will need a CalDAV/CardDAV server somewhere and use each machine as a client and synchronize... or alternatively use `git` or `vdirsyncer`. just some thoughts